# jquery submit form to spring mvc controller

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

In my web application I have a search form as an include.jsp. It gets included on just about every page. There is only one input field on the search form.

I would rather not add a form backing / command object to all my spring mvc controllers for that form. I am looking for a way to use jquery to do a form submit using post and pass the input field to the controller.

I have done some searching on the internet about this and all the answers seem to be for an ajax solution. I don't want an ajax solution.

Here is what my form looks like...

```
<c:url value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/searchResults.htm"                 

<form class="ym-searchform" id="searchResultsForm" name="searchResultsForm" action="${searchResultsFormUrl}" method="post">
   <input id="search" type="search" class="ym-searchfield" placeholder="Search..." />
   <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" class="ym-searchbutton" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Here is what my controller looks like....

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchResults.htm")
public class SearchResultsController {

    @Autowired
    public SearchResultsManager searchResultsManager; 

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean applicationConversionService;   

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitForm(
            ModelMap model,
            @RequestParam("search") String search) {

        List<SearchResult> searchResults = searchResultsManager.getSearchResults(searchText);       
        model.addAttribute("searchResults", searchResults);
        return "searchResults";
    }   
}
```

Can someone give me a jquery snippet I can use to submit the form (POST) to the controller? Or another example that I can use to understand?

thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about spring-mvc, but generally speaking, if you have a form with an action defined to a specific url, clicking the submit button should submit that form to that url.  This leads to the question:  what is happening now?  If you use F12 developer tools on your browser of choice, what webpage is being posted to?  If it's not where you want it to go, where IS it going?  If it's going to the right place, is it not sending the right form data?

Comment: I get a http 400 error. The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. Then when I look at firebug to see what was sent through there is nothing being sent through in the POST.

Comment: Your input needs to have the NAME of "search", not just id.  forms submit values by input name.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Such a key concept of web applications and I did not know it. Thanks.